# Swift 2 NSData as nil

Tags: swift2, nsdata

My application sometimes crashes when it finds `nil` in an NSData variable.  When I try to account for the error, it says "Value of type "`NSData`" can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed.

Also, I have initialized the field, `data` as `var data = NSData()` so I can't understand where nil would even come from.

```
if self.data != nil {
     self.data = data!
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing between the instance variable and a local variable.

- `self.data` is the instance variable, which you have defined to be not nil
- `data` is a local variable, possibly a returned value from some function that you called. It's nilable (i.e. `NSData?`)

If I were to make a guess, your code would look something like this:

```
class MyClas {
    var data = NSData()

    func someFunction() {
        let data = anotherFunction() // This returns an NSData?
        if self.data != nil {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

---

Change it to this:

```
if data != nil {
    self.data = data!
}
```

You can also use optional binding:

```
if let data = data {
    // data is guaranteed to be non-nil in here
    self.data = data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `self.data` with `nil`, not `data`. Hence, I suspect you never assign to `self.data`.

Comment: Is the code you pasted not your actual code (or incomplete)? You essentially wrote `if self.data != nil { self.data = NSData() }`. But since `self.data` is nil before assigning it, the condition will be false.